# foundation 5 accordion in angularjs directive throws exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, zurb-foundation

i get the following error when clicking on an accordion that is generated by an angularjs directive.  i can't really find any clues as to why this might happen other than it has to do with the dynamically created content. those clues tell me to call foundation again within my angularjs controller.  what am i missing?

```
Unhandled exception at line 58, column 7 in
http://localhost:58753/Scripts/foundation/foundation.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
```

which happens here

```
var S = function (selector, context) {
    if (typeof selector === 'string') {
      if (context) {
        var cont;
        if (context.jquery) {
          cont = context[0];
          if (!cont) return context;
        } else {
          cont = context;
        }
        return $(cont.querySelectorAll(selector));
      }

      return $(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
    }

    return $(selector, context);
  };
```

my template

```
<dl class="accordion" data-accordion>
    <dd ng-repeat="x in myCollection | filter: { ParentId :'!', Checked : true }"> 
        <a href="#{{x.Id}}"> {{x.Description}}</a>
        <div id="{{x.Id}}" class="content">
            asdf
        </div>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

my directive

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function myDir() {
    "use strict";

    function link(scope, elem, attr) {

    }

    function ctrl(scope) {

    };

    ctrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

    var ddo = {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: false,
        replace: false,
        templateUrl: '/AngularTemplates/ScopePicker',
        link: link,
        controller:ctrl,
        scope: {
            myCollection: '='
        }
    };

    return ddo;
}

myApp.directive('myDir', myDir);
```

my controller

```
function MyCtrl(scope,http) {
    http.get('/api/somethingcool').success(function (result) {
        scope.foo = result;  // gets passed into myColleciton for the directive
        angular.element(document).foundation();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fingered it out.  html Id fields cannot start with a number. adding some letters before the number handles this requirement.

```
<dl class="accordion" data-accordion>
    <dd ng-repeat="x in myCollection | filter: { ParentId :'!', Checked : true }"> 
        <a href="#foo_{{x.Id}}"> {{x.Description}}</a>
        <div id="foo_{{x.Id}}" class="content">
            asdf
        </div>
    </dd>
</dl>
```